# How to Include Other Models in Loopback?

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

I've read the document here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter

But they are not clear! For example, they give the example:

`User.find({include: 'posts'}, function() { ... });`

Where should this code fit into? Is it in the common/models/user.js? Then what inside the function? what is the returned?

Of course I'm getting frustrated with their documents.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter) you can use an *include* filter with [`find()`](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-find), [`findOne()`](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-findone) and [`findById()`](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-findbyid). I have attached links to respective sections of [API reference](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/).

To use these methods you need your [`PersistedModel`](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel) object (e.g. *User*). Like you mentioned, you can get it in *common/models/model-name.js* (if you store your models there). You can also easily retrieve it from your [`LoopBackApplication`](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#var-app-loopback) object, which you can get in [several ways](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Working+with+LoopBack+objects#WorkingwithLoopBackobjects-Gettingtheappobject). Bottom line is ... you can basically use these methods, wherever you need.

`function() { ... }` argument signalizes a callback. It lets you define a function which is going to be used on a returned instance(s). What is inside that function depends on your needs.